# Windows 10 doesn't let user save files from GUI applications and says "File esauriti". What is this matter about?

Tags: windows, windows-10, hard-drive, gui

While working with a PC in the lab, I've encountered a somewhat troublesome error.

**Problem description:**
No file can be saved from the GUI (whatever GUI, Firefox, Google Chrome, File explorer, etc...) to the main hard drive (C:/ partition). It is still possible to save file on a USB or from a USB to the C:/ partition. However, files can still be saved using a programming language (Python, Java, etc...) writing directly to file. When saving a file using the GUI, you get a pop up window saying "File esauriti" or something like that which could be translated as "No more file available" or something on that line. If you google "File esauriti" you'll get plenty of discussions on this problem (although it is in italian) but no solution nor explaining of what the problem is and what is causing it.

My question is: can someone explain me what this problem is and what is causing it?

I'd like to point out that the hard drive is half empty, therefore space is not an issue. By the way, the computer technician said it's Windows 10's fault, since it is "crap". My gut feeling says I can't completely disagree with him on the fault matter, but still I'd like to know about the problem. I'd like to mention that nothing particular was done on the PC.

Comment: First thing I'd do is run a `sfc /scannow` to fix potential problems. Alternatively, you can use the app `Reset this PC` (search for it in the start menu) to reinstall the windows components. You may need to reinstall some apps, but you can choose to keep your files, so making backups is not necessary if you are careful enough. Though making backups never hurts.

Comment: The problem may be caused by trying to save to C: root, as opposed to a subfolder, if the program is not run as Administrator. Try creating a new folder on C: and saving files into that from an application.